# How can I call a clojure function when a Leiningen build has completed?

Tags: clojure

How can I call a Clojure function when a Leiningen build has completed? I want to do this as I populate a list during compilation and I want to save the list to disk when the compilation has finished

Comment: Use a lein hook. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199188/how-can-i-add-a-build-step-to-leiningen

Comment: Or if it fits your use case, use lein aliases, or even a custom lein task as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644087/how-to-add-a-hook-into-the-uberjar-process-building-with-lein

Comment: Ok, thanks. Make that an offical answer and I will choose it as the official answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways:

1. lein hooks. See [How can I add a build step to leiningen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199188/how-can-i-add-a-build-step-to-leiningen)
2. lein aliases: You'll find some info with examples in https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/286bc3f034e322f91be2a59cc970da49badd08ac/sample.project.clj#L204
3. Custom lein tasks, as in [how to add a hook into the uberjar process (building with lein)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644087/how-to-add-a-hook-into-the-uberjar-process-building-with-lein)